# Bind itemDataSource to select html element?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

Is it possible to bind a List-Binding to a HTML Select () element to display the contents of the binding as  elements?

Im using this right now, which doesn't seem to work:

```
<select data-win-options="{itemDataSource: ...)}"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a programmatical way without declarative binding:

JavaScript part:

```
// Load data
var options = [
    { optionValue: 1, optionText: 'One', selected: false },
    { optionValue: 2, optionText: 'Two', selected: true },
    { optionValue: 3, optionText: 'Three', selected: false }
];

// Fill select box
options.forEach(function (value, i) {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.text = value.optionText;
    newOption.value = value.optionValue;
    if (value.selected) {
        newOption.selected = true;
    }
    myBox.add(newOption);
});
```

HTML part:

```
<select id="myBox"></select>
```

Otherwise, you can use a WinJS.UI.ListView with a template:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211837.aspx