# Bind data in dropdown list in metro app using the Sqlite

Tags: jquery, html, microsoft-metro

I am working over a Windows 8 metro app using(HTML 5, JavaScript) and want to know how i can bind data from the SQLite tables in my dropdown list, please guide or suggest with some source codes. I am using the below mentioned approach, is there any other way to do this job in win metro app

```
 function getcategories() {
    SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath).then(function (db) {
        db.allAsync('SELECT * FROM dbCategorymaster where isActive=' + IsActive + ' order by [order]')
            .then(function (rows) {
                var str = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

                    str = str + '<option value=' + rows[i].id + '>' + rows[i].category + '</option>';
                }
                var ddlcategory = document.getElementById("drpCategory");
                ddlcategory.innerHTML = '';
                ddlcategory.innerHTML = str;
                db.close();
            })
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so: what have you tried?

Comment: I am using SQL Component (https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT) and want to bind the Json data which i received form database and i have below is the sample method which i am trying to do the binding with dropdown and attached the sample code with my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of component do you use to access SQLite?
So for I haven't come across any way to declaratively bind options of a select tag.
You could either use a ListView and its itemDataSource ([as provided by our SQLite component](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT)) or programmatically fill the options like described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111064/bind-itemdatasource-to-select-html-element).

Comment: I am using SQL Component (https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT) and want to bind the Json data which i received form database and i have below is the sample method which i am trying to do the binding with dropdown

Comment: In that case, have you tried using WinJS.Utilities.setInnerHTMLUnsafe(element, text); instead of setting the value directly? Apart from that, your code looks fine.

Comment: On a somewhat unrelated note: glad to see that other people are using our SQLite component, too :) Feel free to open issues if something doesn't work as expected. Also, pull requests for enhancements are welcome ;)